# changing the css to certain classes

Tags: jquery, html

Okay so I have a bunch of tables in my website they all have the same class which is 'item -' and what ever number the table is here is how I did that:

```
$("table").each(function(index){
 $(this).addClass('item-'+index);
 });
```

Now what im trying to do is make it so if the class is anything higher than 'item-8' to make the visibility hidden i tried something like this but it doesn't work. am I in the right track or completely off?

```
$('table').each(function(index){
      if($(this).hasClass('item-'index) > 8){
        $(this).css('visibility','hidden');
      }
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("table").each(function(index) {
    $(this).addClass('item-' + index);
    if ( index > 8 ) {
        $(this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
    }
});
```

Comment: @RodrigoLessa - There was a typo in my code (`visibility` is spelled with one `l`). I updated it.

Comment: They all worked but i chose this answer because you did both my functions in one

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div[class^=item-]').filter(function(e){
    return e >7;
}).css('visibility','hidden');
```

Quick **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/ne972/)** using divs.

Comment: There's no guarantee the the `item-*` class name is the first one.

Comment: @JosephSilber - correct, there isn't. But if there is just the one class it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use css for this? Give each item an "item" class. Provided you don't need IE8 support for this, this just becomes:

```
.item:nth-child(n+8) {
    visibility:hidden;
}
```

jQuery supports nth-child so you can also use that as a selector instead of filter. http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

See also: http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/ and http://jsfiddle.net/gwwar/nneQj/ for a quick fiddle.